# why 127.0.0.1 work even i did not install loopback adapter in win7

Tags: loopback

run ipconfig /all only display my real Ethernet network card, and check the windows device manager/network adapters, also did not find any loopback adapter.

so how my 127.0.0.1 work?

Microsoft do some trick?

I wrote piece of code to find Ms actually add a "**Software Loopback Interface 1**",
what's that? and what's the difference between it with a real Ms loopback adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft do some trick?

Yes. MS put hardcoded 127.0.0.1 in a DLL.

Comment: aha, interesting, good to know.

Comment: Side question: is it possible to disable 127.0.0.1?  What if I removed/temporarily renamed the .dll?  What is the .dll?

Comment: Why would you want to disable it? Every piece of software which uses is will break.